# R Build a sequence of vectors by index

Tags: r, vector

I have a question about generating vectors. There should be a fancy way to achieve this but I am kind of lost in figuring it out. I really appreciate your assists if anyone could help me out. Thanks!

Suppose I have two vectors storing the index:

```
start <- c(11, 26, 55, 110)
end <- c(16, 33, 60, 120)
```

where start variable is the start index while end variable is the end index.

Is there a fancy way instead of a for loop to create a list of vectors like this:

```
[11,12,13,14,15,16]
[26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33]
[55,56,57,58,59,60]
[110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapply(":", start, end, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#OR
lapply(1:length(start), function(i) start[i]:end[i])
#OR
apply(cbind(start, end), 1, function(x) x[1]:x[2])
#[[1]]
#[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16

#[[2]]
#[1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33

#[[3]]
#[1] 55 56 57 58 59 60

#[[4]]
# [1] 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
```